# I need to create animation effect

Tags: flutter, dart

I have tried a lot to do animation exactly the same. I am sharing the link to how I want the animation.

http://stepntoys.com/login-register.php

Same effect when clicking on the Sign Up button and Sign In button.

Try to open in mobile browser or Resize your browser screen as per mobile dimentions

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a look at https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn and in the section of Learn Applied Visual Design, there are many lessons about animation effect.

Comment: Thanks for your attention, but at least provide an example instead of providing references....

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer of your question you can use this code to create animation mode.

```
button:hover {
    animation-name: background-color;
    animation-duration: 500ms;
    
  }
  @keyframes background-color {
    100% {
      background-color: #4791d0;
    }
  }
```